# Random sampling from a 2d list w/o numpy

Tags: python, list, random

i have a huge dataset but to simplify the problem, think about a 4x4 2d list.

want make a new list with 5 elements which is choosen by randomly from the 4x4 list **without** using numpy or any addional libraries.

edit:

```
[['j', 'k', 'z','p'],
 [1,6,8,9],
 [8,True,0,'a'],
 [66,'False', '12', '5]]
```

i want to pick 5 elements of that list ramdomly **with random library functions**

output maybe like a new list of choosen elements:

```
['j', 'False', 'a', 8, 66]
```

hope that it's clear enough.

Comment: sadly its not clear enough yet...
do you want to choose any item in a nested list? can you post what you have tried?

Comment: I'd suggest giving a rough size rather than saying "huge", order of magnitude estimates are enough. e.g. you want this to work with 2d arrays of approx 1 billion by 100, i.e. 10¹¹ elements.  note that you'd almost certainly not be using the standard library at this point, but never mind

Comment: you're right. i'll follow your suggession from now on. thank you @SamMason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Your list right now isn't quite valid syntax, but fixing that up):

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> import random
>>> list_2d = [['j', 'k', 'z', 'p'],
...  [1,6,8,9],
...  [8,True,0,'a'],
...  [66,'False', '12', '5']]
>>> random.choices(list(itertools.chain(*list_2d)), k=5)
['False', '12', 8, 6, 'k']
```

The `itertools.chain` call will flatten it into a 1d list, which the `random.choices` function can handle to sample with replacement:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices

Also, without more detail of the full problem it will be hard to know whether this solution will be good for the "huge dataset"- it creates a new copy of the full list as a 1d list, so if that uses too much memory, we'd need to see where the data is originally coming from, and if you could avoid the list-of-lists structure in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

with the random module you can use a list comprehension:

```
import random

list_2d = [... your list 4X4]
randmly_chosen = [random.choice(random.choice(list_2d)) for _ in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea of flattening `ls` could still be borrowed from `numpy` without any use of its methods:

```
ls = [['j', 'k', 'z', 'p'],
      [1,6,8,9],
      [8,True,0,'a'],
      [66,'False', '12', '5']]

flat_ls = []
for n in ls: 
    flat_ls.extend(n)
from random import shuffle
shuffle(flat_ls) #dynamic change of flat_ls, very fast
>>> flat_ls[:5]
['12', 66, 8, 'j', 'a']
```